# Html or Css Automation

Tags: html, css, automation

I've got this code in my site and I have to automate it. Please help.

```
#vol1
{
    background-image:url(rresim/noveller/1.png);
}

#vol2
{
    background-image:url(rresim/noveller/2.png);
}

#vol3
{
    background-image:url(rresim/noveller/3.png);
}

#vol4
{
    background-image:url(rresim/noveller/4.png);
}
```

...
And I have to make lots of them. So Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by automate then? The better you try to explain your problem, the better help you'll get.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at SASS or LESS.

Comment: I have to made lots of them and all code is same. Only two numbers. And I must add lots of code for "two" numbers. I mean that. I need a code which automates this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use less or sass for that.
Here is [LESS Loop](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature):

```
.generate-vol(4);

.generate-vol(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
    #vol@{i} {
        background-image: url(rresim/noveller/@{i});
    }
    .generate-vol(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

Comment: I know sass but I can't use them because all the site is finished except this so less gone but thanks I try SCSS